# how to run npm commands by clicking on a button in browser

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

Hi I want to run nodeJS Commands e.g. [ionic start myApp blank] when I click on a button i.e. Create new ionic app.
Can any one please help me that how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question sort of reads as a set of requirements. Any code to show? What research have you done? These things will help us help you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer of my own question. By using sockets we can send the command from client to server as a string, and on server using child process we can run that command received in a string via socket.